# Rank-unimodality and Sperner property of higher dimensional partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

I did a google-search but have not been able to find much reference on this problem. So I am asking it here hoping to get some information.

Consider the set of all 4-dimensional Ferrer's diagram contained in an 4-dimensional $m\times n\times p\times q$ box. This is a graded partially ordered set and this is clearly seen to be rank-symmetric. Is there anything known about the rank-unimodality and Sperner property of this poset? What is the current status of research on this problem? Also, is there anything known about the analogues problem for higher dimensional partitions?

Just to add a little background, this problem for 2-dimensional case is well known and has several proofs using linear algebra (by Proctor), lie theory (by Proctor), algebraic geometry (by Stanley) etc., including a purely combinatorial proof by O'Hara. The problem for 3-dimensional partitions has been solved by Proctor using representation theory of lie algebras, although I am not sure if any other interesting proofs are known.